# control ms access scrollbar in continuous form

Tags: vba, windows, ms-access, winapi, scrollbar

I'm implementing a drag and drop simulation in a continuous form.

basically the way it works is, there is list of people in the side and the user can drag a person from the list to a field, (which is a seat list, with fields like Seat1, Seat2, seat3..., and each seat row is a new record).

For the basic drag and drop functionality i'm using the instructions from this link [Drag And Drop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137650), and it is working great.

**now here is my problem**, to know on which record the user is moving the mouse i need to calculate the position of the mouse divided by the detail section,  so while the form is not scrolled down it is working good, but when the form is scrolled down, i need to know first how much the form is down, and this can only be accomplished through a windows API.

so i found that www.lebans.com/conformscurcontrol.htm has exactly the code i need, but that worked only in older versions of ms access, the code that is breaking in the newer vertion is, that he is checking fro a window class name "scrollbar" and calling on it the GetScrollInfo API, but in newer versions there is no class named "scrollbar", but there is a other class called NUIScrollbar [See Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f6e7c597-1354-41c2-b323-a4811d6ff95f/move-datasheet-scrollbar-with-vba-in-access-because-requery-resets-the-focus-to-first-topleft-cell?forum=accessdev), but even when changing it to this name i don't get back a valid scrollbar class (LPSCROLLINFO).

Here is the code from Stephen Lebans

```
Public Function fGetScrollBarPos(frm As Form) As Long
' Return ScrollBar Thumb position
' for the Vertical Scrollbar attached to the
' Form passed to this Function.

Dim hWndSB As Long
Dim lngRet As Long
Dim sinfo As SCROLLINFO

    ' Init SCROLLINFO structure
    sinfo.fMask = SIF_ALL
    sinfo.cbSize = Len(sinfo)
    sinfo.nPos = 0
    sinfo.nTrackPos = 0

    ' Call function to get handle to
    ' ScrollBar control if it is visible
    hWndSB = fIsScrollBar(frm)
    If hWndSB = -1 Then
        fGetScrollBarPos = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Get the window's ScrollBar position
    lngRet = apiGetScrollInfo(hWndSB, SB_CTL, sinfo)
    'Debug.Print "nPos:" & sInfo.nPos & "  nPage:" & sInfo.nPage & "  nMax:" & sInfo.nMax
    fGetScrollBarPos = sinfo.nPos + 1

End Function

Private Function fIsScrollBar(frm As Form) As Long
' Get ScrollBar's hWnd
Dim hWnd_VSB As Long
Dim hWnd As Long

hWnd = frm.hWnd

    ' Let's get first Child Window of the FORM
    hWnd_VSB = apiGetWindow(hWnd, GW_CHILD)

    ' Let's walk through every sibling window of the Form
    Do
        ' Thanks to Terry Kreft for explaining
        ' why the apiGetParent acll is not required.
        ' Terry is in a Class by himself! :-)
        'If apiGetParent(hWnd_VSB) <> hWnd Then Exit Do
```

this the old peace

```
        If fGetClassName(hWnd_VSB) = "scrollBar" Then
            If apiGetWindowLong(hWnd_VSB, GWL_STYLE) And SBS_VERT Then
                fIsScrollBar = hWnd_VSB
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
```

this is how i tried to replace  it

```
        If fGetClassName(hWnd_VSB) = "NUIScrollbar" Then
            If apiGetWindowLong(hWnd_VSB, GWL_STYLE) And 1107296256 Then
                fIsScrollBar = hWnd_VSB
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
```

continue the function

```
    ' Let's get the NEXT SIBLING Window
    hWnd_VSB = apiGetWindow(hWnd_VSB, GW_HWNDNEXT)

    ' Let's Start the process from the Top again
    ' Really just an error check
    Loop While hWnd_VSB <> 0

    ' SORRY - NO Vertical ScrollBar control
    ' is currently visible for this Form
    fIsScrollBar = -1
End Function


' From Dev Ashish's Site
' The Access Web
' http://www.mvps.org/access/

'******* Code Start *********
Private Function fGetClassName(hWnd As Long)
Dim strBuffer As String
Dim lngLen As Long
Const MAX_LEN = 255
    strBuffer = Space$(MAX_LEN)
    lngLen = apiGetClassName(hWnd, strBuffer, MAX_LEN)
    If lngLen > 0 Then fGetClassName = Left$(strBuffer, lngLen)
End Function
'******* Code End *********
```

Hope i'm clear enough, any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your current version of MS-Access? Is it on a 64 bit system? It might be API changes. I'm assuming you're running on 64 bit Windows. One article addresses this at http://www.catch22.net/tuts/64bit-scrollbars

Comment: You might consider using ListView controls which have built-in Drag&Drop support.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same Problem, the following seems to work:

```
Public Const SB_HORZ As Long = 0                ' &H0 (32 bit)
Public Const SB_VERT As Long = 1                ' &H1 (32 bit)
Public Const SB_CTL As Long = 2
Public Const SB_BOTH As Long = 3
Public Const SB_HORZ64_0 As Long = 1107296256   ' &H42000000 (64 bit - invisible)
Public Const SB_VERT64_0 As Long = 1107296257   ' &H42000001 (64 bit - invisible)
Public Const SB_HORZ64_1 As Long = 1375731712   ' &H52000000 (64 bit - visible)
Public Const SB_VERT64_1 As Long = 1375731713   ' &H52000001 (64 bit - visible)
...
eWindowStyle = GetWindowLong(ehWnd, GWL_STYLE)
Select Case eWindowStyle
Case SB_HORZ, SB_HORZ64_0, SB_HORZ64_1
    ' *** Horizontal
    wWinAPIhWndScrollbarHorz = ehWnd
Case SB_VERT, SB_VERT64_0, SB_VERT64_1
    ' *** Vertikal
    wWinAPIhWndScrollbarVert = ehWnd
End Select
...
```

Comment: I will check it out when i have a chance, Thank you